# Bot is not answering

Tags: python

```
async def start_command(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    await update.message.reply_text('Hello, thanks for chatting with me! I am chatGPTbot')
        
async def help_command(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    await update.message.reply_text('I am chatGPTbot, ask me any question so I can help you')
            
async def custom_command(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    await update.message.reply_text('This is the custom command')
```

i tried to chat with it but the result is same no answer yet